# Google sheet download link

Tags: google-sheets

I had designed some content in Google docs, Google sheets and Google slides and want to placed the demo link on my site, demo can be downloaded only by registered users.

Is there any why by which I can create a link by which the site visitors can download the demo google sheets, docs and slides, but the download by link is only possible to the registered users, if any unregistered visitor clicks the link he cannot download the stuff.

Any help on above will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this will help https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing

Comment: When you say registered user, do you mean registered on your site, or registered in google docs?

Comment: Registered on my site......

Comment: "Registered on my site......" What site? How link knows visitor is registered? The question is about site not Google Sheets.

Comment: Is it possible to connect this via any API?

Comment: Depends on site platform. For example if WordPress No API use. Just custom function. Create custom function bind with `is_user_logged_in()` and put in `functions.php`.

Comment: @deadshot. My comment also for you. Thank you.